# Read Each File to One Mapper Exactly

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce problem which should read each file to one mapper exactly and generates solutions. There is a solution which overwrites isSplitable() method of FileInputFormat. But the problem is my code raises error when I overwrite the method such as;

```
public abstract class WholeFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Object, Object> {

    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path filename) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

NoSuchMethodException error raises for WholeFileInputFormat.

Which part am I doing wrong or is there another way to overwrite this method?

Or what should I do to correctly assign one file for each mapper?

**EDIT**

I solved the problem!!! The problem is that I put this code inside my MapReduce class which is raising error. The true location should be as a separate class inside same package with MapReduce class.

Comment: Is your input data actually splittable? For example if you have gzipped data it isn't splittable and you will get 1 file per mapper by default.

Comment: My input data is in .txt format and as far as I know it's splittable my MapReduce. I read before that gzipped data isn't splittable, but I have a confusion about gzipped data. Is file content affected when converted to gzipped version?

Comment: which version of hadoop are you using?

Comment: I'm using hadoop 2.7.3.